# Partial differentiation (Quotient- and chainrule)

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> > Let $u\in C^2(\Omega), \Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^2$.
> >     I have to calculate
> >     $$
> > \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}}{\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)^2}}\right).
> > $$

In order to minimize my writing work, I set
$$
a:=1+\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)^2
$$

My attempt now is the following:

Quotient rule:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}}{\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)^2}}\right)=\frac{\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}\cdot\sqrt{a}-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(\sqrt{a})\cdot\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}}{a}.
$$

Now I tried to calculate $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(\sqrt{a})$.

With the chain rule, I got
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(\sqrt{a})=\frac{\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}}{\sqrt{a}}\cdot\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}}{\sqrt{a}}\cdot\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x\partial y}
$$

All in all, I get

$$
\frac{\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}\cdot\sqrt{a}-\frac{\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}}{\sqrt{a}}\cdot\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-\frac{\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}}{\sqrt{a}}\cdot\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x\partial y}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}}{a}.
$$

Is that right? Can one make this expression easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two suggestions: (a) use subscripts for derivatives; (b) use product rule instead of quotient.
$$
\begin{split} &(u_x(1+u_x^2+u_y^2)^{-1/2})_x  \\
& =u_{xx} (1+u_x^2+u_y^2)^{-1/2} + u_x\left(- \frac12\right) 
(1+u_x^2+u_y^2)^{-3/2} (2u_xu_{xx}+2u_yu_{xy}) \\
& = (1+u_x^2+u_y^2)^{-3/2}\left\{ u_{xx}( 1+u_x^2+u_y^2) 
- u_x (u_xu_{xx}+u_yu_{xy}) \right\} \\
& = (1+u_x^2+u_y^2)^{-3/2}\left\{ u_{xx}( 1+ u_y^2) 
- u_x u_yu_{xy}  \right\} \\
\end{split}
$$
I leave the comparison with your answer to you.