# Writing a PDE in divergence form as a quasi-linear PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> > Let $u\in C^2(\Omega)$ ($\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ limited domain) fullfill the PDE
> >     $$
> > \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}}{\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)^2}}\right)+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}}{\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)^2}}\right)=0\mbox{  in  }\Omega.
> > $$
> >     This is a PDE in the divergence form. Convey this PDE in the following quasi-linear PDE:
> >     $$
> > \left(1+\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)^2\right)\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}-2\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x\partial y}+\left(1+\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2\right)\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}=0\mbox{  in  }\Omega~~(A)
> > $$

Hello, my problem is the following.

Using [Partial differentiation (Quotient- and chainrule)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/523653/partial-differentiation-quotient-and-chainrule), I only get 
$$
\left(1+\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)^2\right)^{-3/2}\cdot\left(\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}\left(1+\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)^2\right)+\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}\left(1+\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2\right)-2\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x\partial y}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)=0~~(B)
$$

and so the equations (A) and (B) differ in the factor
$$
\left(1+\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)^2\right)^{-3/2}.
$$

Where is the mistake, if there is any?

With kindly regards,

math12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no mistake. Since $u \in C^2(\Omega)$, the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \in C^1(\Omega)$, i.e., they are real-valued functions. Therefore

$$\left( 1 + \left( \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \right)^2 \right)^{-3/2} \tag{1}$$

is nonzero (in fact, it is greater than or equal to one). Therefore you can divide both sides of (B) by (1) to recover (A).

Comment: Thank you for your answer!